# Jmeter - How do I add comments to a parameter file?

Tags: performance, automation, jmeter, performance-testing

This may be a somewhat basic question, but how do I add comments to a parameter file for a Jmeter test?

Have seen what purport to be examples using both # and //.
Which is correct?

In need of this as I have a number of tests using a lot of parameters and I need to comment them up such that the next guy to run them will have an easier time understanding them.

Thanks,
Iain

Comment: what is a parameter file for you ? CSV ou properties file ?

Comment: Parameter file is the Jmeter parameter file containing items such as 'Number of Threads', 'Startup Delay' as variables. Storing them in a simple text file.

Comment: What component do you use to load them ?

Comment: Am using a .properties file, loading via the command line. Test is started via a shell script and the properties file specified after the shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you parameter file which is a properties file, comment will be  specified through

> #